# Using PHP and Laravel, why can i not append a variable to a value in an array?

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, this

I am using the Listing Model to create rules for validation and I am trying to add the date() function to the value for one of the array's key/value pairs:

```
class Listing extends Way\Database\Model {

    public $today_date;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->today_date = date("n/j/Y");
    }

    protected $guarded = ['id','created_at','updated_at'];  
    protected $table = 'listing';

    protected static $rules = [
        'deposit' => 'required|integer',
        'date_available' => 'required|date|after:'.$this->today_date,
    ];
}
```

When I submit the form, I get the following message:

> syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

How can I use the date function to append it to the value in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use `$this` in a static function (your `$rules` is static).

You could just use a custom validation

```
protected static $rules = [
        'deposit' => 'required|integer',
        'date_available' => 'required|date|after_today
    ];
```

Then in your app somewhere

```
Validator::extend('after_today', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return ((strtotime($value)) > (strtotime('now')));
});
```

Comment: Great recommendation! Thanks! The only thing I would add then is to add the validation message to app/lang/en/validation.php as "after_today"          => "The :attribute must be a future date."

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$this` to initialise a class property.

you can do it in your constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->today_date = date("n/j/Y");

    self::$rules = [
        'deposit' => 'required|integer',
        'date_available' => 'required|date|after:' . $this->today_date,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make this work. Probably since I'm extending Way\Database\Model class so that might be conflicting with that.

Comment: Static property initialisation in a constructor should be made for singleton class only, just remember that you can't use an [expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) in a property (static or not) initialisation